# Using one class as a RedisHash and an Entity at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have a java class representing my Cart object in my e-commerce application. Now my plan was to store the cart and each of the cart items in Redis until the order is complete and then i would store them in mysql.

Now I have declared a class as my Cart like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    private ShopUser user;

    private String sessionId;

    @OneToMany
    private List<CartItem> cartItems;
}
```

and since I wanted to store it inside mysql and using JPA, I annotated it with @Entity. However I also want to use the fields to store a cart temporarily in Redis as a hashtable.

I also know that annotating the same class with @Entity and @RedisHash will result in a conflict of beans for my repository.

So now I have some questions:

1.Is there a way to annotate one class with @Entity and @RedisHash at the same time?

2.Is using JPA a good practice for a cart mechanism like this?

3.If I should make speerate classes, what are the naming conventions I should use for each?

Comment: Why you want to use Redis? Is it only for keeping data temporary?

Comment: I want to store carts temporarily and then store it in the database when the user checksout

Comment: I suggest adding a boolean flag to the entity with name 'approve' and when the user checks out it change the value of this field to true. However, if you want to keep them in Redis it is better to create a new class for managing it.
Mixing concept is not proposed at all.

Comment: yeah i guess i'm gonna have to create another class, ty for the help